# PowerShell\Regex remove all variable characters in a string before a specific set of characters

Tags: regex, powershell

If I have a variable string 'testawzoid' , which could have anything before "zoid", how do I remove everything before "zoid" regardless of what comes before "zoid".

It could also be "testaxzoid" or "testaanythingzoid" , I just want to keep "zoid"

I have looked at regex and trim etc with no luck. Can anyone point me int the right direction please?
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to keep "zoid" as the content of your variable and remove everything else?  ;-)  Why don't you re-assign the variable with the string "zoid"?

Comment: as `Olaf` pointed out, your description makes no sense. [*grin*] just replace the string with the string you want. ///// however, i presume you are actually wanting something else, would you please give two or three **_realistic_** samples and what result you want from each?

Comment: You can do `$stringVar -replace '.*(?=zoid)'`

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Comment: @Olaf when I was speaking about a variable string, I meant a string which is not always the same. The word 'variable' , in this case is not computer language but rather they way the ancient Romans meant it - late Middle English: via Old French from Latin variabilis, from variare

Comment: @IanB ... so you might work on your skills to ask a specific technical question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @adminofthings stated in above comment you can use

```
"testaxzoid" -replace '.*(?=zoid)'
```

Here is a [tio](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6kktbgksaIqPzNFSUG3KLUgJzE5VUFdT0vD3hYkqKmu8P8/AA) link if you want to test it. The example uses a regex with a positive look ahead, which is explained [here](https://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1).